# Find column names of missing values based on list from other dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

`nominals` is my reference dataset with all the points that shall be measured every day on a certain machine. It has the following simplified structure

```
nominals
+------------+----+----+-----+----+
| point_name |   x|   y|    z|side|
+------------+----+----+-----+----+
|str1        |.   |.   |.    | .  |
|str2        |.   |.   |.    | .  |
|str3        |.   |.   |.    | .  |
+------------+----+----+-----+----+
```

`x,y,z` are the nominal point coordinates. The `point_name` is a unique identifier of the point measured and contains the `side`. Thus, every side has a list of required points to be measured, e.g. in pseudo code `point_name[point_name.side=="L"].unique()`.

The dataset where the actual measurements are stored has a similar structure but one additional column `id` which identifies the machine being measured. Every `id` has a left and right side being measured.

```
actuals
+------------+----+----+-----+----+----+
| point_name |   x|   y|    z|side| id |
+------------+----+----+-----+----+----+
|str4        |.   |.   |.    | .  |.   |
|str5        |.   |.   |.    | .  |.   |
|str6        |.   |.   |.    | .  |.   |
+------------+----+----+-----+----+----+
```

Now, I want to create a new dataset with an additional column with a list of all the points missing from the measurements dataset for every `id-side` couple. In other words, for every `id-side` combination I need to check the list of `point_name` present in the actual measurements agains the nominal ones and find the difference between the two. Expected results would be

```
+-----------------------+-----------+
| id |   missing_L      | missing_R |
+-----------------------+-----------+
|9433| point_1, point_12|  point_14 |  
|9512| null             |  point_15 |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

In the current solution I'm pivoting around `point_name` and checking the columns that have `null` values.

```py
nominals_left = (
        nominals
        .filter(nominals.side == "L")
        .select("point_name")
)
nominals_left_list = nominals_left.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

actuals_left = (
        actuals
        .filter(actuals.side == "L")
        .groupBy("id")
        .pivot("point_name", values=nominals_left_list)
        .sum("x")
    )
actuals_left_final = (
        actuals_left
        .withColumn("missing_L", F.array(*[F.when(F.isnull(c), F.lit(c)) for c in actuals_left.columns]))
        .withColumn("missing_L", F.expr("array_join(missing_L, ', ')"))
        .select("id", "missing_L")
    )
```

Is there any easier or more efficient way to do this? Also it seems I have to explicitly do the same check on every `side` to avoid creating false positive nulls due to the point belonging to the other side. It would be nice to group altogether over `id` and `side`.

Comment: Hi @Guido It would very helpful if you could provide an example with real data or a real scenario. It is difficult to follow the given example

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the data and make an anonymous complete version to test would take too long I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way after researching a little bit more. I simply create a list of all the required points from the nominal table, join it with the measurement table on `side`, and then do a difference between these two columns of arrays. Seems to work fine.
Here is an example given the `nominals` table and the `actuals` table.
First create a list of all the nominal points per `id` and `side`

```py
nominal_list = (
    nominals
    .groupby("side")
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.col("point_name")))
    .withColumnRenamed("collect_list(point_name)", "nominal_points")
)
```

then join over a similar dataset created with measurements with the additional `id` column (note the order of the arrays when calling `F.array_except`).

```py
missing = (
    actuals
    .groupby(["id", "side"])
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.col("point_name")))
    .withColumnRenamed("collect_list(point_name)", "measured_points")
    .join(nominal_list, "side")
    .withColumn('missing', F.array_except('nominal_points', 'measured_points'))
)
```

Note that this is slightly different from what I asked in the beginning as I have the side as additional column and not hidden in the column name, i.e. `missing_L` and `missing_R`.